# How to access array from one class in another class

Tags: java, arrays, oop

I have coded a little VBA before, but this weekend I have decided to have a look at Java. The following is based on code copied from the web. I can populate an array named anArray, but how do I then access that data from within doWord below?  In other words, how do I get the test if(anArray[1][1]="Test"){} to work? Thanks in advance.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final String[][] anArray;                    // declare the array
    anArray = new String[14][4];                 // create the array
    anArray[1][1]="Test";

    // Start CounterDownRunner
    Thread myThread = null;
    Runnable runnable = new CountDownRunner();
    myThread= new Thread(runnable);
    myThread.start();

    // End of onCreate
}

// Timer
public class CountDownRunner implements Runnable{
    // @Override
    public void run() {
        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
            try {
                doWork();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }catch(Exception e){
            }
        }
    }
}

public void doWork() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try{

                if(anArray[1][1]="Test"){
                    // Do somthing
                }

                // access data in anArray
            }catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    });
}

// End of MainActivity
```

}

Comment: Your `anArray` is declared *inside* of the `onCreate` method and so is visible only from within the method. If you want a variable visible throughout a class, then declare it as a field of the class. If you want other classes to be able to see the field, then give this class a public getter method.

Comment: Thanks.  I have written the code and got it working.  In case anyone is interested, I will post an extract of the updated code.

Comment: public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public class SharedData {
        private String name[][] = new String[1440][4];    // private = restricted access

        // Getter
        public String getName() {
            return name[1][1];
        }

        // Setter
        public void setName(String newName) {
            this.name[1][1] = newName;
        }
    }

    SharedData myArray = new SharedData();